# Best way to use getString()

Tags: android, string, oncreate, getstring

I'm having some problems on where and how to place and call the getString().

I tried at the beginning of my activity where I usually define it but always get an error. Should it be only after onCreate()?

Some of my strings I use it very often so I don't want to use getString() every time I use them.

Is this the correct way?

```
private String helloWorld = getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the top of your file do:

```
private String helloWorld;
```

And then, in onCreate(),

do:

```
helloWorld = getString(R.String.hello_world).
```

The problem is that getString needs a reference to the activity context, which has not been associated with your class until onCreate is called.